# Android dagger api 21 compatibility

Tags: android, compatibility, dagger-2

I developed app with dagger library on api version 25. But now I tried app on 21 api version and it doesn't working. It's caused by dagger.

Here is error log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldagger/internal/Preconditions;

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "dagger.internal.Preconditions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/package-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/package-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

My dagger version: 2.11-rc1.

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: share gradle file in question...

Answer (score 0):

Solved by update build tools version

Comment: what did you update your build tools version to? and what was it originally?